# Why cant center an image inside a 'div' with 'float' right or left?

Tags: html, css

I have enclosed an image inside a nested div `.box`. If it is not floated the image can be exactly centered to the `.box`, but when I `float` it `left` or `right` the center alignment goes away! I have 4 images with various sizes that need te be centered inside their own `.box`. How can I fix it?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="con">
   <div class="box">
      <img src="../_images/icon-test.png">  
    </div>  
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.con {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background: #996600;
}

.box {
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-color: #333333;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Why you use `float` if you want to center element? You either float it or center it, not both.

Comment: @Justinas , i want to center the image to the .box div, not the div element,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` for this.

Change your `display: table-cell` to `display: flex`.

Then change `text-align:center;` and `vertical-align:middle;` to `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;` to center it vertically and horizontally.

Edit: Then I have also added a max-width of 150px to the image, to stop it expanding out of the container when the image is bigger than it. Props to @Hkidd for pointing out that this happens.

```css
.con {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #996600;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: right;
}
img {
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what about the browser support of the flex syntax? What will happen if the OP has to support iOS Safari for example?

Comment: So what happens if the image exceeds the size of its parent?

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

I think you have to position the `img` `absolute`, so it will be positioned absolute to its parent `.box` since `.box` is positioned relative. Also the `display: table-cell;` is unnecessary since the `img` is not inside a table.

This is what I came up with:

```css
.con {
  background: #996600;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
.box {
  background-color: #333333;
  float: right;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}
.box img {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="box center">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what happens if the OP has images of various sizes?

Comment: @CalvT you are right,  I have 4 different images of various sizes, to be placed in 4 boxes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single image as in the question, you can use the `line-height` solution which places the image exactly in center of the `.box` div & use `vertical-align: middle` on the image. Works on all browsers & simple to understand.

Refer code:

```css
.con {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #996600;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
  line-height: 150px;
}
img {
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```